# Unable to get node from simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I understand this question has been asked, but all solutions I've found have not worked for me.

Given this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 
    <test>
        <blah>
          <x>
          filler
          </x>
        </blah>
    </test>

)
```

How do I get the `<x>` value?

I've tried

```
$doc = simplexml_load_string($xml_response);
print_r($doc->test->blah->x);
print_r($doc[0]->test->blah->x);
print_r($doc->{'0'}->test->blah->x);
print_r((string)$doc->{'0'}->test->blah->x);
print_r((string)$doc[0]->test->blah->x);
print_r((string)$doc->test->blah->x);
```

Here's the raw xml:

```
1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xxx>
    &lt;test&gt;
        &lt;blah&gt;
            &lt;x&gt;fillertexthere&lt;/x&gt;
        &lt;/blah&gt;
        &lt;fillertexthere&lt;/Reason&gt;
    &lt;/test&gt;
</xxx>%
```

Comment: If `test` is your root node, you should not mention it : `$doc->blah->x`. Provide the raw Xml data here to be sure

Comment: @Pierre okay, I've added the raw xml ('just changed the names because it contained important info'). `test` is not my root node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) contains one string. I think that is because your xml contains `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

What you could do is first use [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) and then load your string.

*(I have removed this line `&lt;fillertexthere&lt;/Reason&gt;` and `%` from your raw xml)*

```
$xml_response = <<<DATA
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <xxx>
        &lt;test&gt;
            &lt;blah&gt;
                &lt;x&gt;fillertexthere&lt;/x&gt;
            &lt;/blah&gt;
        &lt;/test&gt;
    </xxx>
DATA;
$xml_response = htmlspecialchars_decode($xml_response);

var_dump($xml_response);
```

This will look like:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["test"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["blah"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
      ["x"]=>
      string(14) "fillertexthere"
    }
  }
}
```

You can echo the value of x like this:

```
echo $doc->test->blah->x;
```